# Creating arrays from csv columns in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv, collections, web-deployment

I've never worked with csv files before and I'm hoping to create arrays in php from the columns.

So for example the csv would look something like this:

Name, Address, DOB

john doe, 22 grove street, 06,06,2006

i'd like each of the columns to be an array named by the column headings. Any time I parse the file(test.csv) i get arrays of the table rows instead.

Comment: Can you post your code how you handle the csv and show us how the csv is structured?

Comment: You're going to have problems with commas in the date unless the date is quoted `john doe, 22 grove street, "06,06,2006"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will do the work for you. And you can see the real working script of the exactcode at this url:

http://sugunan.net/demo/csv1.php

```
$i=0;
$filename = 'data1.csv';
$contents = file($filename);



foreach($contents as $line) {
    $line = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $line );
    $line_array = explode(",",$line);
    if($i==0)
    {
        foreach($line_array as $key=>$val)
        {
            $csv_heading[$key] = trim($val);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach($line_array as $key=>$val)
        {
            $csv_array[$i][$csv_heading[$key]] = $val;
        }
    }
    $i++;
}

print_r($csv_array);
```

data file url: http://sugunan.net/demo/data1.csv